# Message in postdispatch

Tags: magento2, event-observer

Can't make messages to appear on frontend. I have an observer on event:

```
<event name="controller_action_postdispatch_cms">
        <observer name="some_module_controller_action_postdispatch" instance="Some\Module\Observer\PostdispatchFrontendActionControllerObserver" />
</event>
```

`Some\Module\Observer\PostdispatchFrontendActionControllerObserver` `execute()` method looks something like this:

```
 public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
            __('success message')
        );

        return $this;
     }
```

I can't see any messages on frontend. why is that?

Comment: In the title you say "Message in predispatch" and then you observe `_postdispatch`. Is it intentional?

Comment: my bad, sorry. Its about postdispatch

Answer (score 0):

Try to add messages to your block:

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->addMessages($this->messageManager->getMessages(true));
    parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

then add your block to layout:

```
 <referenceContainer name="page.messages">
        <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\ValidationMessages" name="checkout.cart.validationmessages"/>
    </referenceContainer>
```

Look how it is implemented in Magento modules:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Block/Cart/ValidationMessages.php

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

Comment: All I want to do it to create an observer on 
<event name="controller_action_postdispatch">
In the observer I want to add system message (success or error). The massage need to be shown on cms/index/index page or any product page. the message block is already there!
The message doesnt show. Messages stack and are shown f.e. when I add a product to a cart. Then I can see spam of my messages.